# Columns not lining up in HTML

Tags: html, drupal-7

I am new to HTML and was asked to figure out how to work in a Drupal 7 website.

Although I know some basic HTML, I am trying to create a basic page with three columns that are aligned.
I used this HTML code found on google, but the columns aren't lined up evenly.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>
            ANGLED STYLE (TYPE 29)</h3>
        Maximum aggression for fast stock removal. Used on both flat surface and edge work. The angle provides greater surface contact for stock removal on flat surfaces.</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>
            &nbsp;</h3>
        <h3>
            FLAT STYLE (TYPE 27)</h3>
        <p>Smooth grinding, blending and finishing. Used primarily on flat surfaces and slight contours.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>
            &nbsp;</h3>
        <h3>
            MORE TEXT</h3>
        <p>Some more text here.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

When I try to google a fix, I keep seeing answers for grids or tables.

Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?

[Screen shot of the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBh2S.png)

Comment: remove blank `<h3>
            &nbsp;</h3>`

Comment: Wow. Can't believe that's all it was. Thanks @Rohit

Comment: I've noticed as I add content the columns still don't align... they aren't even across. Am I using the wrong HTML for the formatting?